# Dependency injection как можно сделать лучше?

Tags: javascript, ооп, typescript

В общем делаю как то так, думаю как сделать так чтобы можно было обратиться к существующему объекту.

```
export class Hand {
    private render:Render;
    constructor(render:Render){
        this.render = render;
    }

    public view(){
        this.render.test();
    }
}

export class Render {
    private hand:Hand;
    public method(){
        this.hand = new Hand(this);
    }

    public test(){
    }
}

let render = new Render();
```

Может переменную `render`  и другие складывать в какой то массив или объект и из него тащить и в не го же добавлять новые созданные

И что если мне в `Hand` вдруг понадобится обратиться ещё к одному объекту который я возможно создам в процессе. Как правильно делегировать объект?

Нашел что то тут https://github.com/asvetliakov/Huject но что то сложнова то для понимания, нужно разбираться

Вот ещё https://github.com/pleerock/typedi это более понятно

Comment: А что конкретно не устраивает в существующем подходе?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в принципе и так можно жить, но чем больше связей тем сложнее конструктор или больше методов которые нужны только для того чтобы прокинуть ссылку на объект.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Например в Hand  я создам объект Card  а в нем создам объект Cat  и в Cat  мне понадобится Render, мне придется прокидывать ссылку через все классы

Comment: Если вы _правильно_ инкапсулируете обязанности классов, вам не придется прокидывать что-то очень глубоко. Постараюсь написать развернутый ответ в ближайшее время (если никто не опередит).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev  буду благодарен, в Symfony  например там в контроллере можно через this->get('name service')  обратится к любому ранее созданному сервису, хотелось бы что то подобное сделать

Comment: А вот за прямое обращение к контейнеру надо бить по рукам, хоть в symfony, хоть в JS ;)

Comment: можно попробовать посмотреть в сторону [декораторов](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html)